# subsite size in C#

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development

How do I programmatically create a webpart to get  subsite size in SP 2013 using c#?

Anyone can point me out to the right direction?

Comment: You have a Nice Storage Metrics report in a SharePoint if you want to see without single line of code

Comment: thanks, I know.  it's business requirements in a big custom project.

Comment: Are you looking for SSOM or CSOM solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get all subsite size using C# Server-Side-Object-Model try the below code:**

```
void GetSiteSize()
{
    long siteCollectionSize = 0;
    string baseUrl = "http://site collection url";

    using (SPSite mainSite = new SPSite(baseUrl))
    {
        foreach (SPWeb web in mainSite.AllWebs)
        {
            long webSize = GetSPFolderSize(web.RootFolder) + web.RecycleBin.Cast<SPRecycleBinItem>().Sum(r => r.Size);

            if (web.Url.StartsWith(baseUrl))
            {
                label.Text = string.Format("({0} {1}", web.Url, FormatSize(webSize)));

            }
        }
    }


}

public static long GetSPFolderSize(SPFolder folder)
{
    long folderSize = 0;

    foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
        folderSize += file.TotalLength
            + file.Versions.Cast<SPFileVersion>().Sum(f => f.Size);

    folderSize += folder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().Sum(sf => GetSPFolderSize(sf));

    return folderSize;
}

public static string FormatSize(long size)
{
    if (size > Math.Pow(1024, 3))
        return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 3)).ToString("#,#.##") + " GB";

    else if (size > Math.Pow(1024, 2))
        return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 2)).ToString("#,#.##") + " MB";

    else if (size > 1024)
        return (size / 1024).ToString("#,#.##") + " KB";

    else
        return size.ToString("#,#.##") + " Bytes";
}
```

**Code Ref:** [Calculating Size of Site Collection, Sub Sites in Multiple Ways](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/calculating-size-of-site-collection-sub-sites-in-multiple-w/)